# jmeter Error when changing to java or groovy

Tags: jmeter

I am using the  and I get error

> import package is not defined at line 2

when switching to groovy or java. I am using version 3.1 jmeter and java version 1.8.0.

the sampler is  jp@jc

Line 2 is

```
import java.io.File;
```

I am tried moving down to java1.7 but this does not work either

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please show the code you use.

Comment: Please clarify your question as otherwise it will be a candidate for closure. It is too vague.

Comment: JP@GC is any third-party plugins set for JMeter, please add your test plan

Comment: Hi, you were right it was very vague. The sampler is JP@GC WebDriver Sampler and it seems to only support javascript.

Comment: import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.util.Random;
import openqa.selenium.OutputType.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
String baseUrl = "http://www.plexify.com";
WDS.browser.get(baseUrl + "/");
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();

Comment: Hi Does this make sense?